# How to convert a iterable variable to single item with groupby in C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a sql query which returns a list of rows from site table(a site belongs to a company);

```
Dictionary<int, List<Site>> contactSites = null;

   var sites= _dataContext.tContacts
                       .Where(c => c.ContactId == userId)
                        .SelectMany(c => c.Sites);
```

I want to group by them with company id and add them to a dictionary;

```
contactSites = sites.GroupBy(x => x.CompanyId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Since I select Many from the query I get casting issue..
How can I overcome this?

Comment: This is completely unclear "*Since I select Many from the query I get casting issue.*" can you paste the exception

Comment: if you can guarantee the resulting query will only ever return a single item you could use `.FirstOrDefault` but it's a little hard to tell if this is actually what you mean.

Comment: @JohnB Yes That is waht I meant.But i will get more not a single row object

Comment: @TheGeneral I couldn't take a screenshot of my visual studio,but it is casting issue as JohnB said. I'll get more than one  row of results

Comment: @Ratha can you post a plain vanilla sql statement as to how you would achieve your desired result?

Comment: Can you add your entity definitions? My first suspicion is that Contact.Sites is possibly a ManyToMany relationship to something like a ContactSite entity, in which case you might need .SelectMany(x => x.Sites.Site) since your variable is pre-definied. You can try: `var testData = sites.GroupBy(x => x.CompanyId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());` with a breakpoint to see if that still errors, and if not, inspect the Type of "testData" in the debugger.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks yes im trying many to many relationship. This edmx lists lot of attributes, Ill try your  and see